# WCF идеи для тестирования

Tags: c#, алгоритм, .net, тестирование

Написал класс для общения программ по средствам **Windows Communication Foundation**. Перешел на этап тестирования, и понял, что особо идей на что тестировать то и нету у меня.

На данный момент тестируется на подключение, отправку, прием простых сообщений (небольшого класса).

**Вопрос**: Какие исключительные моменты могут возникнуть при работе с WCF?

Comment: а что вы собираетесь тестировать именно, протокол передачи данных WCF? Уточню немного, зачем тестам работать с WCF?

Comment: больше надо протестировать работоспособность написанного класса, на непредсказанные случаи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вы планируете тестировать логику работы класса (методы, функции) то флаг вам в руки, ибо unit тестирование именно для этого существуют. А используя Mock'и вы спокойно можете изолировать свой класс от поставщиков данных и полностью покрыть его тестами. Каким макаром тут участвует WCF я не понимаю. И опять же, даже если вы планируете писать интеграционные тесты то для них надо будет описывать своего клиента к WCF сервисам что опять не оправдано ибо смысла тестировать тесты нет (прошу прощения за каламбур). Правильней сделать покрытие тестами клиента отдельно замокав вызовы сервисов, а сервисы соответственно изолировав от своих поставщиков данных. Надеюсь пояснил достаточно развернуто. В комментарий не поместилось, пусть будет ответом :).